# jquery insertion method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a look on this code:

```
 $('li').add('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>')
 .css('background-color', 'red');
```

Although the new paragraph has been created and its background color changed, it still does not appear on the page. To place it on the page, we could add one of the insertion methods to the chain.But what is that method and how to insert it on the chain

Comment: Where do you want to insert what? You currently selected all `<li>`s [and](http://api.jquery.com/add) a new paragrah.

Comment: @Bergi what do u mean ??

Comment: Have you checked [the](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/) [documentations](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)?

Comment: @Bergi i m selecting all the list but not selecting all the paragraph instead creating a paragraph

Comment: @Bergi can i use appendTo method?

Comment: Yes, why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: Or, wait. You can't just add `appendTo` as it would append all selected elements (the `<li>`s and the paragraph) to the same element - which is invalid, since listings need to be contained by ul/ol and paragraphs must not.

Comment: @Bergi but how to insert that paragraph element .For that u need t to first take it out from the current set.How to take it out??which method will help me here?

Comment: Then just do not include it in that set in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Use append instead of add :

```
$('li').append('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>')
  .css('background-color', 'red');
```

[add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) only changes the jQuery set, not the DOM.

Comment: ...but beware, because `$('li')` is very likely to select more than one element, resulting in multiple paragraphs being appended (one to each `li`), all with the same `id`, which is invalid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right. I suppose the code given by OP is just for demonstration but just in case it's better to point this.

Comment: Maybe it's more appropriate to appen an li element into the ul list: $('ul').append('<li><p id="new">new paragraph</p></li>')
  .css('background-color', 'red');

Comment: @dystroy from my style and not from ur style how to insert that paragraph element .For that u need  to first take it out from the current set.How to take it out??which method will help me here?

Answer (score 0):

why not do something like this

```
$('#li-id').html('< p id="new">new paragraph< /p>');
```

or

```
$('#li-id').append('< p id="new">new paragraph< /p>');
$('#new').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: I formatted your answer for you. You should have a look at the toolbar when editing. There's also a link to a detailed documentation of the markdown format.

Comment: Thanks! appreciated. Actually I'm new to this so wasn't aware. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want this:

```
$('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>')
  .css('background-color', 'red')
  .appendTo(something); // a selector, jQuery element etc
```

Comment: but i want it at a time along with the list

Comment: …to do what? Of course you could do `.add('li')` after that chain

Comment: is there any way to just take that paragraph element out from the current stack?

Comment: `last()` should do that, but I'm convinced that it would be bad practise for doing what you actually want. Please, add to your question how the DOM looks before the operation and how you expect it to look afterwards.